# Javascript to modify a variable in an existing on-page script that can't be changed manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in a situation where I'm working with a vendor-provided system that has built in validation scripts that can't be modified.

One of the scripts on the page calls a validation method related to the number of characters in a textbox.

It passes the character count limit as a static number in the method call. The static number is from a configuration file, which I can change. The problem is that I need that number to change based on a value the user selects from a drop down.

What's happening is I have to append content in the textbox on form submit. The content I append includes a value from a drop down that has variable lengths.

The script I have running to append the content in the text box is working just fine. The problem I run into is the user enters the maximum amount of text they can (there is a character countdown) and when they hit submit, the system adds the content from the drop down but then truncates the end of the user's message because it is now longer than the accepted number.

Since this is a vendor / closed system, my options for adjusting existing on-page scripts, form elements, etc are extremely limited. I can add scripts (including jQuery scripts) to modify the DOM.

Any ideas on how to approach something like this would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT

This isn't a working example, but maybe illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
<select name="selectedname" id="selectedname">
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<span id="errormessage"><!-- this is where you would see the text counting down --></span>
<script>
  vendor_script_that_counts_down_text_and_validates_length(arg1, arg2, 500)
</script>
<button id="send"></button>
```

My Script:

```
/* Attempt to add the name to the question*/
if (window.jQuery) {
    //Adding this to prevent conflicts with existing javascript
    jQuery.noConflict();
    // Adding usual jQuery symbol to the local scope of this method
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $("#send").on('click', function(e) {
         var valueSelected = getName($); // this is a function that gets the value of the dropdown
         var message = "This message is for " + valueSelected + ". The message begins here:\n\n";
         $("#message").val(function(index, userMessage){
            return message + userMessage; 
         })
      });
    });
}
```

In terms of how the scripts are currently working together, they aren't and I guess that's the crux of my question, can they work together? Is there a way I can modify my script to change the number used in the validation script call (500) based on the dropdown value selected with the constraints that I can't modify any html or on-page scripts other than the one I created?

Comment: [Add some code. Maybe a reduced but working example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I can add something that is somewhat representative of what's going on, but I can't add the vendor-supplied validation scripts that would replicate the functionality. Is that still helpful?

Comment: Well in some way or the other, you have to show us, how your scripts are working together. As it is, this is to abstract.

Comment: I added a few details - not sure if this really helps. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you added, it seems that the vendor function is a global function. If that's the case, you could overwrite it with a new one, giving you the possibility to alter/manipulate the third parameter.

E.g.: (adding this after the vendor script is loaded, but before the function get's called):

```
vendor_script_that_counts_down_text_and_validates_length = function (orgFunc) {
  // return a new function
  return function (arg1, arg2, charCount) {
    // add your code...

    // call the original function
    return orgFunc(arg1, arg2, charCount || 500);
  };
}(vendor_script_that_counts_down_text_and_validates_length);
```